# Receiving ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method 'model_name' for nil:NilClass) Denshobato

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working on a two-model chat feature using Denshobato. The issue that I'm having is Denshobato may require the **conversations_controller** and **messages_controller** -- I'm currently using those two controllers for a different feature in my project. I instead, decided to use **discussions_controller** and **discussion_messages_controller**. When I attempt to render the form for the discussions inside of the index for the employer_meetup_controller. I receive the undefined method 'model_name' error. The code that I wrote is below. How can I setup Denshobato to accept my discussions_controller and discussions_message_controller aliases? Btw, I'm using two gems for this feature, **denshobato_chat_panel** and **denshobato**.

discussions_controller.rb

```
class DiscussionsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_account_signed_in?

  def index
    @discussions = current_account.my_conversations.includes(:sender)
    @trash = current_account.trashed_conversations
  end

  def create
    @discussion = current_account.hato_conversations.build(discussion_params)
    if @discussion.save
      redirect_to discussion_path(@discussion)
    else
      redirect_to :discussions, notice: @discussion.errors
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @discussion = Denshobato::Conversation.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :discussions if @discussion.destroy
  end

  def show
    @discussion = Denshobato::Conversation.find(params[:id])
    redirect_to :discussions, notice: "You can't join this conversation" unless user_in_conversation?(current_account, @discussion)
    @discussion_message_form = current_account.hato_messages.build
    @discussion_messages = @discussion.messages.include(:author).page(params[:page]).per(25)
  end

  %w(to_trash from_trash).each do |name|
    define_method name do
      room = Denshobato::Conversation.find(params[:id])
      room.send(name)
      redirect_to :discussions
    end
  end

  private

  def discussion_params
    params.require(:denshobato_conversation).permit(:sender_id, :sender_type, :recipient_id, :recipient_type)
  end
end
```

_discussions_form.html.slim

```
= simple_form_for @discussion, url: :discussions do |form|
  = fill_conversation_form(form, user)
  = form.submit 'Start Discussion', class: 'btn btn-primary'
```

discussions_controller (index.html.slim)

```
- if @trash.any?
  h1 Trash
  - @trash.each do |room|
- @discussions.each do |room|
  = interlocutor_image(room.recipient, user.user_profile.avatar, 'imag-circle')
  = link_to "Discussion with: #{interlocutor_info(room.recipient, :first_name, :last_name)}", discussion_path(room)
  p = room.messages.last.try(:body)

  = interlocutor_image(room.messages.last.try(:author),
          user.user_profile.avatar, 'img-circle')
  - if room.messages.last.present?
  p = "Last message from: #{message_from(room.messages.last, :first_name, :last_name)}"
  = button_to 'End Conversation', discussion_path(room),
          method: :delete, class: 'btn btn-outline-danger'
  = button_to 'Move to Trash', to_trash_path(id: room),
          class: 'btn btn-warning', method: :patch
  = button_to 'Move from Trash', from_trash_path(id: room),
          class: 'btn btn-warning', method: :patch
  hr
```

discussions_controller (show.html.slim)

```
= simple_form_for @discussion_message_form, url: :discussion_messages do |form|
  = form.input :body, class: 'form-control'
  = fill_message_form(form, current_account, @discussion)
  = form.submit 'Send message', class: 'btn btn-primary'
  = render_denshobato_messages(@discussion, current_user)
  - @discussion_messages.each do |msg|
    = msg.body
    hr
```

discussion_messages_controller.rb

```
class DiscussionMessagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :current_account!

  def create
    discussion_id = params[:denshobato_message][:discussion_id]
    @discussion_message = current_account.send_message_to(discussion_id, discussion_params)

    if @discussion_message.save
      @discussion_message.send_notification(discussion_id)
      redirect_to discussion_path(discussion_id), notice: 'Message sent'
    else
      redirect_to discussion_path(discussion_id), notice: @discussion_message.errors
    end
  end

  private
  def discussion_params
    params.require(:denshobato_message).permit(:body, :author_id, :author_type)
  end
end
```

employer_meet_up_controller.rb

```
- @users.each do |user|
  = user.user_full_name
  - unless conversation_exists?(current_account, user)
    - if can_create_conversation?(current_account, user)
      - if user_in_black_list?(current_account, user)
        p 'This user in your blacklist'
        = button_to 'Remove from black list',
                remove_from_blacklist_path(user: user, klass: user.class.name), class: 'btn btn-info'
      - else
        = button_to 'Add to black list',
                black_list_path(user: user, klass: user.class.name), class: 'btn btn-danger'
        = render partial: 'discussions/discussion_form', :locals => {:title => "Discussion"}
  hr
```

user.rb

```
  def user_full_name
    first_name + " " + last_name
  end

  def full_name
  # denshobato method
    "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end

def image
    user.user_profile.avatar.url
  end

denshobato_for :user
  denshobato_chat_panel
```

employer.rb

```
 denshobato_for :employer
   denshobato_chat_panel
```

routes.rb

```
  mount Denshobato::DenshobatoApi => '/'
  resources :discussions
  resources :discussion_messages
  patch :to_trash, to: 'discussions#to_trash', as: :to_trash
  patch :from_trash, to: 'discussions#from_trash', as: :from_trash
  post :black_list, to: 'blacklists#add_to_blacklist', as: :black_list
  post :remove_from_blacklist, to: 'blacklists#remove_from_blacklist', as: :remove_from_blacklist
  root 'home#index'
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def current_account
    current_user || current_employer
  end

  def current_account_signed_in?
    user_signed_in? || employer_signed_in?
  end

  def notification_count_for(user)
      Notification.unread_count(user)
  end

  def user_logged_in?
    !current_user.nil?
  end

  def activate_account_time_zone
    return yield unless current_account # nothing to do if no user logged in
    return yield unless current_account.time_zone && ActiveSupport::TimeZone[current_account.time_zone] # nothing to do if no user zone or zone is incorrect
    Time.use_zone(ActiveSupport::TimeZone[current_account.time_zone]) do
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Console log

```
Processing by EmployerMeetUpController#index as HTML
  Employer Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "employers".* FROM "employers" WHERE "employers"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "employers"."id" ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Rendering employer_meet_up/index.html.slim within layouts/application
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" ORDER BY "users"."first_name" ASC LIMIT $1 OFFSET $2  [["LIMIT", 46], ["OFFSET", 0]]
  Denshobato::Conversation Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "denshobato_conversations".* FROM "denshobato_conversations" WHERE "denshobato_conversations"."sender_type" = 'Employer' AND "denshobato_conversations"."sender_id" = 1 AND "denshobato_conversations"."recipient_type" = 'User' AND "denshobato_conversations"."recipient_id" = 1 LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  Denshobato::Blacklist Load (0.0ms)  SELECT "denshobato_blacklists".* FROM "denshobato_blacklists" WHERE "denshobato_blacklists"."blocker_type" = 'Employer' AND "denshobato_blacklists"."blocker_id" = 1 AND "denshobato_blacklists"."blocked_type" = 'User' AND "denshobato_blacklists"."blocked_id" = 1
  Rendered discussions/_discussion_form.html.slim (781.1ms)
  Rendered employer_meet_up/index.html.slim within layouts/application (827.2ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1248ms (ActiveRecord: 2.0ms)



ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `model_name' for nil:NilClass):
    1: = simple_form_for @discussion, url: :discussions do |form|
    2:   = fill_conversation_form(form, user)
    3:   = form.submit 'Start Discussion', class: 'btn btn-primary'

app/views/discussions/_discussion_form.html.slim:1:in `_app_views_discussions__discussion_form_html_slim__1021469361_78616992'
app/views/employer_meet_up/index.html.slim:12:in `block in _app_views_employer_meet_up_index_html_slim__524570216_75009660'
app/views/employer_meet_up/index.html.slim:1:in `_app_views_employer_meet_up_index_html_slim__524570216_75009660'
app/helpers/application_helper.rb:21:in `activate_account_time_zone'
```

Answer (score 0):

You're getting this error because `@discussion` is nil. Check your controller methods and make sure it's present and correctly passed.

The reason why you're getting this error is because ActiveRecord objects use the `ActiveModel::Naming` module to generate the associated URL helpers (like where the form should post to, unless you otherwise specify) and form helpers (like the prefix of your field names)

More info on `ActiveModel::Naming` http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Naming.html